# "There is insufficient space on the device"--This is not duplicate

Tags: insufficient-memory

My mobile is Micromax Canvas HD Plus .It has 4 GB inbuilt memory and 16 GB external memory card.I have selected SD Card as default location to install apps but still when I try to install app from Play Store it shows above error.My SD Card is nearly empty.

I searched a lot .Uninstalling Play store updates,Clearing Cache nothing worked.

Comment: Can't edit the previous comment so...

I am certain the question I link is the same issue. Your phone comes with really low memory for modern phones. What phone is it anyway? Keep in mind that cache can be recreated by apps, and apps seems to always try installing on internal memory instead of SD card. Moving them over doesn't always help either, as some data can remain on the internal memory. Phones can have a limit too to when they deny installing more, as they need some space for temp files. Just like on a PC.

Comment: Can't we modify behavior of apps

Comment: No, as apps prefer to me on internal as SD cards can be slower, and if unmounted wrong, can cause issues like crashes and hang-ups. Usually the app only lets you transfer things like their own cache or "extras". You can root the phone to achieve full transfer, but this is quite advanced step. Also, some phones MAY support the full-app transfer to SD card, tho I am not sure what phones actually do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about how internal memory you have, it's about how big your /data partition is. Apps can only install to this partition, and even if you had your internal memory empty, apps wouldn't be able to fill this memory because they are only stored in /data. To fix this, you can try to resize partitions, but it's not simple, so be sure to know what you're doing before you corrupt your partitions.

Comment: I want to do that.I am not so new to this.But new in android stuffs