# my internal memory is empty but cant add new apps

Tags: applications, sd-card, insufficient-memory, storage

Not enough storage when loading apps to my phone why is this and my internal memory is empty, also new 4gb memory card is brand new.

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question; please see [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) for some background and first-aid. Trouble in such cases is not storage per se, but *device internal storage*. If that's down, no matter how much free space you've got on your internal/external SD card, you'll get this error.

Answer (score 0):

Open settings>storage>miscellaneous and delete all the files from here
Also delete cached data(by touching it)It happened with me too but now every thing is fine I found a file named 0 in miscellaneous and on deleting it my phone started working properly

Answer (score 0):

I think that this has already been answered in [this thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/101967/there-is-insufficient-space-on-the-device-this-is-not-duplicate/101972#101972)

You may have sufficient internal strage space, but not enough space on the */data* partition.